# $A$ not similar to a triangular matrix over $\mathbb R$ then $A$ is similar over $\mathbb C$ to a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is thus:

> Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix with real entries. Prove that, if $A$ is not similar over $\mathbb{R}$ to a triangular matrix, then $A$ is similar over $\mathbb{C}$ to a diagonal matrix.

Assume $F$ is an arbitrary field.

I have a theorem that says:

> $T$ is triangulable over $F$ if and only if the minimal polynomial for $T$ is the product of linear polynomials over $F$.

So this tells me that the minimal polynomial for $A$ is not the product of linear factors (e.g. it has at least $1$ non-linear term). I know $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed so you can factor all polynomials into linear factors. I don't quite see how that makes $A$ automatically diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

The theorem I have for diagonalizable reads:

> $T$ is diagonalizable over $F$ if and only if the minimal polynomial for $T$ has distinct roots in $F$ with no repeats.

but I can have repeated nonlinear terms in the first theorem to be non-triangulable which would stop me from applying the second theorem.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is cubic since $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix. The characteristic polynomial has real coefficients since $A$ is a real matrix.

A real cubic necessarily has one real root but your characteristic polynomial cannot have more than one real root since it does not factor over the reals (why?). What does the conjugate root theorem say about the complex roots of your polynomial? Why does that suggest $A$ is diagonalizable over the complex numbers?

Comment: @AvatarOfChronos My pleasure.

Comment: Any matrix can be put in "Jordan Normal Form" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) which has eigenvalues on the main diagonal, 0s or 1s immediately above the main diagonal, all 0s below.  That is an "upper triangular" matrix unless the numbers immediately above the main diagonal are all 0s in which case the matrix is diagonal.

Comment: @user247327 The Jordan Canonical Form is always available over the complex numbers, but not over the reals.