# Suppose $A: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a diagonalizable operator whose all eigenvalues are $1$.Is it true that $A$ is identity operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose $A: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a diagonalizable operator whose all eigenvalues are $1$.Is it true that $A$ is identity operator?

Someone told me that for proving this we have to go to $\mathbb C$ by using tensor product.I don't understand why we need all this thing? Cant we just say that since $A$ is diagonalizable therefore $A=P^{-1}DP$.By hypothesis $D$ is identity matrix hence $A$ is identity?Why do we need to extend base field?Am i missing something?

Comment: Its diagonalizable, so its minimal polynomial splits into distinct linear factors. So the minimal polynomial of $ A $ is $ x - I $

Comment: @the_hermit Could you please read my comments?

Comment: Regarding your comment on extending the base field, in general, for a matrix $ A \in M_{n}(F) $, where $ F $ is a field, it may happen that all the eigenvalues may not lie in $ F $ and we might have to go to an extension $ K $ in which you have all the eigenvalues. Here, you assume that $ A : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ is diagonalizable, so you already know that all eigenvalues are in $ \mathbb{R} $. So you do not have to worry about going to $ \mathbb{C} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all eigenvalues are $1$ and $A$ is diagonalizable, then there is an invertible matrix $S$ with $SAS^{-1}=I_n$, hence $A=S^{-1}I_nS=I_n$.

Comment: So we don't need to extend base field from $R$ to $C$ ?

Comment: No, because you assume already "diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$", i.e., $SAS^{-1}=D$ diagonal.

Comment: Can we do this without assuming that?

Comment: Depends on what you want to assume. In the extreme, you can assume that $A$ is already the identity. Then there is nothing to prove. You may assume that $A$ is not diagonalizable. Then it is false.

Comment: I know if all eigenvalues are $1$ then $A$ need not be identity.A simple example in case of $2 \times 2$ matrix can be given.Do you know any problem in which we need to extend base field for proving that a matrix is diagonalizable?I've never seen such question so i'm excited for that.Sorry for troubling you

Comment: A good example is perhaps [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371172/a-not-similar-to-a-triangular-matrix-over-r-then-a-is-similar-over-c-to-a-diagon).

Comment: I see.Thank you!Do you know any other such problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has a basis of eigenvectors $\{v_{i} \}$. Choose $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $v = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i}$. Hence, $Av = A \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}Av_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i} =v$. It follows that $A = I$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true since all matrices conjugated to the identity are the identity